# Hiding RadTooltipManager using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, telerik

I have a RadToolTipManager on my website. What I want is to hide this tooltip when I click anywhere on the screen but RadToolTipManager. I have the following jQuery which seems to work fine except that it hides the tooltip even when the tooltip itself is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').bind('click', function(event) {
    var activeTooltip = Telerik.Web.UI.RadToolTip.getCurrent();
    if (activeTooltip && activeTooltip.isVisible()) {
      activeTooltip.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('form').bind('click', function (event) {

                if ($(event.target).is(".panelWrapper, .panelWrapper *")) {
                    return;
                }

                var activeTooltip = Telerik.Web.UI.RadToolTip.getCurrent();
                if (activeTooltip && activeTooltip.isVisible()) {
                    activeTooltip.hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to do:

```
$('html').click(function() {
    var activeTooltip = Telerik.Web.UI.RadToolTip.getCurrent();
    activeTooltip.hide();
});

$('form').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: this does not allow any other control to fire.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why it is not working because the way you are getting the

```
 var activeTooltip = Telerik.Web.UI.RadToolTip.getCurrent();
```

activeTooltip  is undefined so you will get an error :

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'getCurrent' of undefined
```

Try To get the activeTooltip In this way :

```
var activeTooltip = $find("<%=activeTooltip.ClientID%>");
```

If you are using chrome or safari browser try to go to console after clicking to
see if there is any script error.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tooltip-client-side-overview.html - the getCurrent() static method is official.